# Is it possible to scale just the container size(without scaling content) using css3 scale?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want a div to occupy view port when a user clicks on it. currently, I have set css3 transition to the div. And setting the width and height property using javascript. And animation happens. But it is not smooth. It looks jerky.

So, I want to use some built in function to scale. And I ended with css3 scale(). But it scales the content as well. I just want the div to expand. Not the content.

Is this is achievable or Is there any other way to do this? And I want to implement css3 solution not a javascript solution.

Comment: How about only changing dimensions as width and height? Once you remove the scale the animation should run smoother since it takes quite some calculation power.

Comment: I am already doing it. But it does not looks smooth.

Comment: The way I read it you are changing dimensions by using javascript. My suggestion is to use css transitions for it (sorry for not being clear). You could then use javascript to change the class of the object to 'trigger' the animation.

Comment: The real issue is the jerkyness. That said, post your code and/or create jsFiddle with this issue. Trying to add new code on top of some issue can create more complications. IMHO fix the smaller problem before you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hacky way to do this in pure CSS, which is to add an interior div to hold the content - then apply the scale up to the element and apply an equal scale down to the interior div itself. In this way, your content will stay the same size.